# How to serve an image with a different random name each time with Django?

Tags: python, django, nginx, amazon-s3

I'm implementing some sort of image captcha for a client, and my client requested the images be served with a different URL on each challenge attempt. My web server is Django and I currently serve the images using nginx locally but I plan to host the images on S3. What's the best approach to do this? I could:

1. Use Django to declare a python view that would download the image from where it is originally hosted and serve it under the random name;(the name saved under the challenge attempt instance).
2. Use Django to call on the file system or to call Amazon API to copy the file to a random name, when the challenge is initialised, and then delete that file later when triggered by the solving of a challenge relating to that image.

The reason I'm asking is because Django isn't efficient in serving static data.

Any other ideas?